# Soap signature with WebServicesClientProtocol and sha256

Tags: c#, soap, digital-signature, sha256

I am trying to implement a SOAP client using Web reference. Resulting signature is valid but uses sha1 algorithm.

**Is there a way how to use sha256 instead?**

Several solutions can be found but they all work with XmlDocument (SignedXml) directly.

Following code sets SignatureMethod to sha256 but sha1 is used anyway.

```
var client = new EetRef.EETService();// Inherits from Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol
var cert = new X509Certificate2("01000004.p12", "eet");
var token = new X509SecurityToken(cert);
var messageToken = new MessageSignature(token);
//Trying to register sha256 provider.
CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RsaPkCs1Sha256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
//messageToken.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod is null
messageToken.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
client.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);
client.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(messageToken);
client.CallSomeMethod();
```

Resulting soap:Header

```
<soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action wsu:Id="Id-9ef8e35c-6107-4d31-83ba-6006b0e76557">http://fs.mfcr.cz/eet/OdeslaniTrzby</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID wsu:Id="Id-7e6b8643-0760-4356-8062-c914a2b0b5a9">urn:uuid:575cf2f5-296b-4dff-ab3d-0d3bf75c72a5</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo wsu:Id="Id-abc8e30a-5a23-49c6-9ac3-d53c652e21e1">
      <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To wsu:Id="Id-d8a0047e-48f2-4bd7-8d16-c89ff1cdf128">https://pg.eet.cz/eet/services/EETServiceSOAP/v2</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-9a3390ec-8f6d-4bf9-8d8f-b3d591ff599f">
        <wsu:Created>2016-08-21T17:53:50Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2016-08-21T17:58:50Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-6d5709b8-0ba3-413a-ba48-942ad6e763f1">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <Reference URI="#Id-9ef8e35c-6107-4d31-83ba-6006b0e76557">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>9NhSyQ67wzxd4lwaG+0PL6ztgMs=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-7e6b8643-0760-4356-8062-c914a2b0b5a9">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>cLktOiRAwoDSlKMMM8++gqc/TS8=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-abc8e30a-5a23-49c6-9ac3-d53c652e21e1">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>iOJ6axh+PU+ciOe+rSKpJbjlw9w=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-d8a0047e-48f2-4bd7-8d16-c89ff1cdf128">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>yoaPc5P0gQPQipRira4FPlbUZlY=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Timestamp-9a3390ec-8f6d-4bf9-8d8f-b3d591ff599f">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>eE1zIA5xoOnHWWbdb90X2bylySs=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Id-a5b17a91-2f27-4bb2-baa5-0f5afe812ace">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>8iCvJtbGDPGtZ60+mwZof++5ym4=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>Hy8yVARA8FIUxXfxkGU3i3zp2CZN4xREGrdEY4RQxC11rwrX8+i1hkwkE/KapH97iFcx4ryBF9sy+K64SoDEndmAipgHcdeZhbixBKVno7eLPnnaKtSQf6YGRgaOcvLdf/ELwYNXQa5fMbBmlL5rX15fXhPhjEJagMidppiDCLy48MGfd3fGJEwAlu5I2hh8jjumzJuuzk7pLB7oY9sCArcNCFDY2FSHgnnFEDT0krHnmYUePJZ8qjSrZ44D0YdChC07l9GpXLaNxVklMIRqpa3ALjohVV7bkFSskbs+to8ueXq6cUX3kwUiRTyf3lHxKfVjLAX16fEbguHiZVHa3A==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-6d5709b8-0ba3-413a-ba48-942ad6e763f1" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body wsu:Id="Id-a5b17a91-2f27-4bb2-baa5-0f5afe812ace">
  ...
```

The certificate is a playground certificate and can be downloaded from http://www.etrzby.cz/assets/cs/prilohy/CA_PG_v1.zip (The certificate supports SHA256)

Comment: Did you solved it? We both probably work on EET (Czech Republic)? :)

Comment: Not yet. It seems that Web reference doesn't support that. But for some brief period of time EET servers accepted SHA1 as well. I am not sure if I broke something on my part or they changed it but it doesn't work now. Anyway I am probably going to implement it from scratch. Maybe hit me on vojtech.basta@dynabit.cz so we can share what we figgure out?

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who is working on implementing EET (in Czech Republic). I did not find a solution using a Web reference.

But there is an Apache licenced library on Github:

https://github.com/l-ra/openeet